# What is the best approach when receipt fails validation?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

When receipt validation fails on OSX, I mean the application receipt, Apple says to exit with code 173, that will force iTunes to load and the receipt to be downloaded from Apple. If the receipt fails for some reason (the user cancels the iTunes request for password, user has no internet, etc., ) the app simply won't load.

But for iOS the thing is different. There is no `exit(173)`. What is the best approach with iOS? When the app loads, it tries to verify the receipt, the receipt is not there, then we request a new receipt using

```
SKReceiptRefreshRequest *refreshReceiptRequest = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:@{}];
```

Now what? there are two situations: request fails (no internet, no receipt, etc) or request succeeds, there is a receipt but receipt is not valid (may be some piracy attempt (?)). What should the developer do, exit the app?

If the validation fails for inapp purchase and the good is non-consumable you simply disable the good until you can verify or the user does a restore purchase, but in the case of failed validation of the app receipt you are talking about the whole app.

What is the best approach to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apple Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html) -

> **Refresh the Receipt If Validation Fails in iOS**
>
> If validation fails in
>   iOS, use the SKReceiptRefreshRequest class to refresh the receipt.
>
> Do not try to terminate the app. At your option, you may give the user
>   a grace period or restrict functionality inside your app.

So it doesn't say exactly what you should do, but it looks like you can display a message and or/disable functionality - this could include providing no functionality at all I guess - disable all user interface elements

Comment: Add a UI that suggests purchasing the app, or the in-app purchase.

Comment: ok, but it is strong to say "this copy is pirate, please buy the app".

Comment: I would probably be a bit more diplomatic in case of some other cause.  Perhaps just "unable to verify application purchase at this time.  Please restart the application" or something

Comment: What message do you display when the receipt validation fails (or they don't enter the credentials)?  Is it informative?